# TypeScript React Application in ASP.NET Core 6.0 with VS 2022

Tags: reactjs, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

does anyone know how to create a react application in ASP.NET Core 6.0? There is a template in VS 2022 to create a react app:

[image: Template used]

This works fine, I can run the application just fine. But I would like to use TypeScript instead of JavaScript.

When I follow [these](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-typescript/) instructions, the application won't start anymore. Simply renaming the js files to tsx after adding TypeScript support is not enough.

Does anyone have any experience with this? Of know how to solve this issue.

Error's after renaming the js files to tsx:

[image: Errors]

When try to run npm start I get the following error:

[image: NPM Start Error]

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

So there is a problem with your "prestart" in your `package.json` file.

I think the way to do it is to use `ts-node` and change it to this:
`node --loader ts-node/esm ./src/aspnetcore-https.ts && node --loader ts-node/esm ./src/aspnetcore-react.ts`

source:
https://www.nolanbradshaw.ca/net-react-typescript-template